# Getting rid of unnecessary loops

Tags: c#, xna

In my game I'm going to have a lot of interactions in which I'll need to see if a player has an item, and if he does and something else is true, then do an action. Described in the following code.

```
private void SetTinderInPit()
{
    MouseState currentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();

    if (player.NextToFirePit == true)
    {
        foreach (Item item in player.PlayerInventory.Items)
        {
            if (item.ItemName == "tinder")
            {
                foreach (Item pit in allItemsOnGround)
                {
                    if (pit.ItemName == "firepit" && 
                        pit.ItemRectangle.Contains(MouseWorldPosition) &&
                        currentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed &&
                        oldMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
                    {
                        item.ItemName = "empty";
                        pit.ItemName = "firepitwithtinder";
                        pit.Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("firepitwithtinder");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        oldMouseState = currentMouseState;
    }
}
```

As you can see, this is ugly to look at and I think that there would be a better way to do this, but I'm not sure how. Since there will be a lot of these types of methods, I'm wondering what would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is this related to XNA?

Comment: One of by biggest pet peeves is when people compare `bool` variables to `true` or `false`.  Please just do `if(player.NextToFirePit)`  there is no need for the `== true`.

Comment: @juharr Right I agree, but it is syntactically correct and some people prefer it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving working code. Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @PaulG The `Content.Load<Texture2D>` would make it seems so. Probably immaterial to the question though.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Right, just thought I'd add it to his tags to make this question easier to locate.

Comment: To @CodeCaster's point, perhaps you should ask "How to find an element without a loop", which would make it not a code review. I personally think its on-topic on both sites.

Comment: I would use **Dictionary<string, Item>** for one thing. Waay faster and not mere sugar syntax as LINQ provides

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you could get rid of (actually hide) the loops altogether by using some LINQ:

```
private void SetTinderInPit()
{
    MouseState currentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();

    if (player.NextToFirePit)
    {
        Item tinder = player.PlayerInventory.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ItemName == "tinder");
        if (tinder != null)
        {
            Item firepit = allItemsOnGround.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ItemName == "firepit" && i.ItemRectangle.Contains(MouseWorldPosition));
            if (firepit != null && 
                currentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed &&
                oldMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
            {
                tinder.ItemName = "empty";
                firepit.ItemName = "firepitwithtinder";
                firepit.Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("firepitwithtinder");
            }
       }
       oldMouseState = currentMouseState;
    }
}
```

This has the added advantage of short-circuiting the loop when the item is found. It also makes it easy to check against things other than the name (like an "IsFlammable" or "CanContainFire" property) so you could use multiple items instead of just "tinder" and "firepit".

If you *actually* intended to remove all firepits and tinder, use:

```
private void SetTinderInPit()
{
    MouseState currentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();

    if (player.NextToFirePit)
    {
        foreach (Item tinder in player.PlayerInventory.Items.Where(i => i.ItemName == "tinder")
        {
            foreach (Item firepit in allItemsOnGround.Where(i => i.ItemName == "firepit"))
            {
               if (firepit.ItemRectangle.Contains(MouseWorldPosition) &&
                currentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed &&
                oldMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
                {
                   tinder.ItemName = "empty";
                   firepit.ItemName = "firepitwithtinder";
                   firepit.Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("firepitwithtinder");
                }
             }
       }
       oldMouseState = currentMouseState;
    }
}
```

Quick caveat; this code will remove *all* firepits with the *first* tinder, leaving the other tinders unscathed. I could unravel the loops to remove everything, but this function matches the provided one; and besides, I'm assuming thats not the intended behavior.

Note you do not need `ToList` anywhere because you are not modifying the collection during enumeration. You can always modify the items *in* the collection, proved with the following test:

```
class IntWrapper
{
    public int value;

    public IntWrapper(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<IntWrapper> test = new List<IntWrapper>() { new IntWrapper(1), new IntWrapper(2), new IntWrapper(3), new IntWrapper(4), new IntWrapper(5) };

        foreach (IntWrapper i in test.Where(i => i.value == 1))
        {
            i.value = 0;
        }

        foreach (IntWrapper i in test)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.value);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the given code is not short-circuiting the loop can we really safely say that this would give the same results?  What if there are multiple tinder items and firepits?  Otherwise this looks good.

Comment: @juharr Only the OP can say. I would expect to only have (1) of my tinders removed when making a fire, especially if I spent a bunch of time collecting (100)! His code would remove them all. Change `FirstOrDefault` to `Where` (with the same foreachs he had instead of if statements) and you would get it, I'll add it in.

Comment: @juharr See my edit for the error in my previous comment, it would simply remove all firepits (though that isn't obvious without a lot of thinking). I'll leave how to actually remove everything as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Do we need to call .ToList() on the .Where statements since we are modifying the items in the loop? I get confused on that one...

Comment: @RufusL You aren't modifying the collection itself (adding or removing an item), so no, you don't. I added a test program that proves this.

Comment: I dont want any firepits removed and only one tinder. The firepit just changes texture and name at the point when the mouse is clicked and the player has any amount of tinder in the inventory. This is a good point. If the player has more than one tinder, I'd have to add a check to see if the player has 0 and then set the item to empty. I am not removing or adding anything to the inventory list

Answer (score 1):

The only real change I would make to your existing code would be to move the check for mouse state early on, to avoid checking this multiple times in your loops. In addition I would use Linq to shorten the conditions (by removing the 'if' statements):

```
MouseState currentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();

// I would get all the conditional checks out of the way up front first
if (player.NextToFirePit &&
    currentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed &&
    oldMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
{
    foreach (var tinderItem in player.PlayerInventory.Items
        .Where(item => item.ItemName == "tinder"))
    {
        foreach (var firePit in allItemsOnGround
            .Where(item => item.ItemName == "firepit" &&
                           item.ItemRectangle.Contains(MouseWorldPosition)))
        {
            tinderItem.ItemName = "empty"; 
            firePit.ItemName = "firepitwithtinder";
            firePit.Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("firepitwithtinder");
        }

    }
}

oldMouseState = currentMouseState;
```

An alternate idea, since you were looking for a way to get rid of the 'ugly' code, would be to move some of this functionality to the player object.

Comment: +1 for moving the state checks to the earliest point.  But note you don't need those `ToList` calls.

Comment: I wasn't sure about the ToList(). Since we are modifying the items that we are iterating over, I thought it best to force the query evaluation at once. I get confused on that one sometimes!

Comment: The `ToList` call is actually going to cause more iterations in this case.  First to create the list then to iterate the list in the `foreach`.  Without it the `foreach` will just iterate the Linq query once.

Comment: The exception comes when you modify the *collection*. See my post for a test program that proves this is safe.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I'll remove them.

Comment: Is there a reason you put all of the state checks at the beginning of the method?

Comment: @ChristianFrantz Yes. The reason is for a slight performance gain in the cases where there are more than one tinder item in the inventory. The original code was checking the MouseState values `tinderCount * firepitCount` times. My code checks it once if the player is near a firepit. So the original code would perform better (by not performing this check one time) if the player has no tinders, but my code performs linearly better if the player has more than one tinder, and exponentially better if the player is also near more than one firepit.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use LINQ more.

*Note that this is written in Notepad, not visual studio so is more of a pseudo-code.*

```
private void SetTinderInPit()
{
    var currentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();
    if (!player.NextToFirePit) return;

    player.PlayerInventory.Items.Where(item => item.ItemName == "tinder").ToList().ForEach(item =>
    {
        allItemsOnGround.Where(x => x.ItemName == "firepit" &&
            x.ItemRectangle.Contains(MouseWorldPosition) &&
            currentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed &&
            oldMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
                .ToList().ForEach(pit =>
                {
                    item.ItemName = "empty";
                    pit.ItemName = "firepitwithtinder";
                    pit.Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("firepitwithtinder");
                });
    });
    oldMouseState = currentMouseState;
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but BradleyDotNET already provided a similar answer using real code.

Comment: Also, the materialization with `ToList()` is unnecessary and will produce unnecessary overhead. The collection is never modified. Even if it was, `Reverse` would likely be more efficient.

Comment: Personally I'm against the use of `ForEach`.

Comment: @juharr Care to elaborate on that? Is it considered bad practice? Not trying to be rude but this is your second opinion-based comment concerning coding practice but you haven't gotten into detail as to why.

Comment: @PaulG I think [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) can explaing better than I.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET You cannot do `ForEach()` without `ToList()`

Comment: @Steve Another reason not to use it.. You iterate over every list an additional time than is needed when a simple `foreach` will suffice.